# How change List type on ObservableList and filter it?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, observablelist

I change my list:

```
var viewModels: List<AuthorizationViewModel> = emptyList()
```

on

```
var viewModels: ObservableList<AuthorizationViewModel> = ObservableArrayList<AuthorizationViewModel>()
```

And in place where i filtering:

```
viewModels = viewModels.filter { !it.shouldBeDestroyed }
```

I get next error:

```
 required: ObservableList<AuthorizationViewModel> 
 found: List<AuthorizationViewModel>
```

Because `.filter()` return List, but **how i can filter** my ObservableList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write next extensions:

```
fun <T> List<T>.toObservableList(): ObservableList<T> {
    return ObservableArrayList<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }
}
```

and use:

```
viewModels = viewModels.filter { !it.shouldBeDestroyed }.toObservableList()
```

That solved my problem.

But if u need to add callback, u can do smth like this (problem with instance):

```
val filteredList = viewModels.filter { !it.shouldBeDestroyed }
viewModels.replaceWith(filteredList)

fun ObservableList<AuthorizationViewModel>.replaceWith(list: List<AuthorizationViewModel>) {
    this.clear()
    this.addAll(list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more directly:

```
viewModels.removeIf { it.shouldBeDestroyed }
```